Migration of table from csv to postgres using python
My target in this script was  using a csv create a table named product into the postgres db . The DB will get structure from columns header in csv(I have set string type). Then, I will insert into table and also handle null data by putting default for string. However, issue is that the process doesn't end it going on and on . I had to keyboard interrupt it. Even though I have set the process in batches, the code is not able to handle the data.
import csv
import psycopg2
import os

def create_table_from_csv(csv_file, table_name, conn):
    # Open the CSV file and read the first row to get column names
    with open(csv_file, 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
        header = next(csv_reader)
        
        # Debug: Print the header to check column names
        print("Header:", header)

    # Sanitize column names
    sanitized_columns = []
    for column in header:
        sanitized_column = ''.join(c if c.isalnum() else '_' for c in column)
        sanitized_columns.append(sanitized_column)

    # Debug: Print sanitized columns to verify
    print("Sanitized Columns:", sanitized_columns)

    # Construct the CREATE TABLE SQL statement
    create_table_sql = f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} ("
    create_table_sql += ", ".join(f"{col} TEXT DEFAULT 'default_value'" for col in sanitized_columns)
    create_table_sql += ");"

    # Execute the SQL statement to create the table
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(create_table_sql)
        conn.commit()

    # Return the sanitized column names
    return sanitized_columns

def load_data_from_csv(csv_file, table_name, conn, sanitized_columns, batch_size=1000):
    # Open the CSV file and read data up to the specified batch size
    rows = []
    unprocessed_rows = []
    print("load_data_from_csv")

    with open(csv_file, 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        csv.field_size_limit(2147483647)  # Increase the field size limit for the CSV reader
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
        header = next(csv_reader)  # Skip the header row
        
        for i, row in enumerate(csv_reader, 1):
            if i <= batch_size:
                # Debug: Print the row to ensure correct parsing
                print("Row:", row)
                # Pad the row with default values for missing columns
                padded_row = row[:len(sanitized_columns)] + ['default_value'] * (len(sanitized_columns) - len(row))
                rows.append(padded_row)
                
                # Debug: Print padded row to ensure correct padding
                print("Padded Row:", padded_row)
            else:
                unprocessed_rows.append(row)

    # Insert the rows into the database
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        for row in rows:
            insert_sql = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} ({', '.join(sanitized_columns)}) VALUES ({', '.join(['%s'] * len(sanitized_columns))})"
            cur.execute(insert_sql, row)
        conn.commit()  # Commit the transaction

    # Write unprocessed rows to a temporary file
    temp_csv_file = csv_file + '.tmp'
    with open(temp_csv_file, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as temp_f:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(temp_f, delimiter='\t')
        csv_writer.writerow(header)  # Write the header row
        csv_writer.writerows(unprocessed_rows)  # Write remaining rows

    # Replace the original CSV file with the temporary file
    os.replace(temp_csv_file, csv_file)

    return len(rows)  # Return the number of rows processed

def main():
    # Connect to PostgreSQL database
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname="openFoodDb",
        user="developer",
        password="securepassword",
        host="localhost",
        port="5432"
    )

    # Specify the CSV file and table name
    csv_file = 'en.openfoodfacts.org.products.csv'
    table_name = 'products'
    batch_size = 4  # Define the batch size

    # Create table based on CSV schema if not exists
    sanitized_columns = create_table_from_csv(csv_file, table_name, conn)

    # Process a single batch of rows from the CSV file
    rows_processed = load_data_from_csv(csv_file, table_name, conn, sanitized_columns, batch_size)
    print(f"Processed {rows_processed} rows.")

    # Close the database connection
    conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Well, I have tried to look over the code. I think issue might be with my need to lessen the csv, because I had saved the unprocessed files. Even though, I have saved in batch but it might not solve it.


DO NOT use f strings. psycopg2 has a the sql module for building dynamic SQL safely. 2) Use io.StringIO() to build an in memory CSV file. 3) Use psycopg2 Copy to copy the CSV to the table.

